# Use sixxs subnet on one machine

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipv6

I've got a sixxs subnet with aiccu on my debian vps, and want to use the complete subnet at my vps. Currently only the 2001:4dd0:f000:000f::2 is usable. My config:

(ip a)

```
3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: sixxs: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/sit 109.111.111.11 peer 70.11.11.111
    inet6 2001:4dd0:f000:000f::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::0006:e000/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

eth0 and lo are not important, I think.

How can I use the complete /64 on my vps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add the IPv6 addresses that you want to use to the interface. For example like this:

```
ip -6 addr add 2001:4dd0:f000:000f::3/64 dev sixxs
```

Comment: I am getting "icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: No route" for the new added address.

Comment: Can you show your interface configuration after you add the address?

Comment: `3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: sixxs: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/sit 109.111.111.11 peer 70.11.11.111
    inet6 2001:4dd0:f000:000f::3/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:4dd0:f000:000f::2/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::0006:e000/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: It might be that the point-to-point link addresses are filtered on the SixXS side. You should also have a routed `/64` subnet. Try using the addresses from that one instead of using the addresses of the tunnel itself.

Comment: It was really a sixxs issue. I've switched to tunnelbroker.net and all works fine.

Comment: I think that SixXS is just doing stricter filtering on addresses that you aren't supposed to be using. But happy to hear that HE is working for you :-)